# z-index in IE8 quirks mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I want my child div to be behind the parent div. I have used `z-index: -1`. It works fine for IE8 standard mode, but in Quirks mode the child div is shown above parent div.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
               "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">         
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
    <style type="text/css">
     .first{    
         width: 400px;
         height: 300px;
         background-color: blue;
         position:absolute;
         }

     .second{   
       width: 600px;
       height: 300px;
       z-index: -1;
       background-color: red;
       position:absolute;
      }
     </style>
    </head>
 <body>
     <div class="first">
          I am parent div
        <div class="second">
             I am child div
        </div>
     </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Why are you even bothering with quirks mode?  YOU control how your page renders, not your user.  If you have a valid doctype and use an X-UA-Compatible meta or header, then IE won't render in quirks mode.  What's the point?

Comment: yes but i am working on some client issue in quirks mode.I need a solution in quirks mode